# Prove: if $0<a_n,b_n$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ then if $\sum b_n<\infty$ then $\sum a_n<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ such that there is $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ that for all $n_o\leq n$:

a. $$0<a_n,b_n$$

b.$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$$

Prove:  if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n<\infty$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n<\infty$

Let assume $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=\infty$ then by the ratio test we get:

$$1\leq q\leq\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$$ So

$$
0<a_n\leq a_{n+1}$$

And $a_n$ is monotonic increasing, if $a_n\not \to 0 $ then we are done, else $a_n\to 0$ then

$$0<a_n\leq0$$

Contradiction.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio test does not guarantee the ratio of terms simply because the series converges or diverges.

---

Since all numbers are positive, we can rewrite the inequality as
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}\le\frac{a_n}{b_n}
$$
Then, by induction,
$$
a_n\le b_n\frac{a_1}{b_1}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\le\frac{a_1}{b_1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n
$$

Answer (score 0):

The statement

> Let assume $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=\infty$ then by the ratio test we get:
>
> $$1\leq q\leq\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$$

is wrong. For example, the sequence $(a_n)$ could be $a_n=1$ if $n$ is odd, while $a_n=2$ if $n$ is even. The ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ could be less than $1$ for some $n$.

You need to try something else.

Comment: If for the sequence you gave $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq q <1$ for any $n_0\leq n$ then the series converge which it can not be as $a_n\not \to 0$

Comment: @newhere My series does not converge. It is NOT the case that "for all $n$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\lt1$".